# Looking for a freeware software/app that can solve eigenvalue problems symbolically

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, software

I'm taking a quantum mechanics course and my homework involves extremely tedious algebra to solve symbolic eigenvalue problems. I'm looking for a software that I can give matrices with symbolic entries and get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. What is best?

Comment: Will you be able to use it for tests?

Comment: Actually, yes! The exams in this course are all take-home.

Comment: Mathematica and Maple have student editions for less than $100. SageMath is free. However, my advice is to get more comfortable with paper and pencil calculations. Not all courses are going to have the same policy. And if you are planning to become a physicist, you should have facility with math.

Comment: What you consider extremely tedious calculations now are small potatoes compared with what awaits in more advanced physics courses.